# Sorting a list before executing the guard clause in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've created an example where I have a list of integers:

```
mylist = [4,3,1,6,9]
```

and I have a function that prints out the maximum value in the list depending on whether or not the list has a length greater than 0. But instead of writing a function to print the maximum value, i want to sort the list in descending before hand and just return the head like so:

```
place :: [Int] -> Int
place numlist
    quicksort numlist --is it possible to sort a list beforehand before running the guard clause??
    | length numlist /= 0 = biggestVal
    where biggestVal = head numlist
```

where the quick sort function is:

```
quicksort :: [Int] -> [Int]  
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a >= x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a < x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

In other words, I'm trying to quicksort the list before executing the where clause instead of having to write

```
where biggestVal = head $ quicksort numlist
```

Comment: Sorting a list just to find the biggest element is inefficient. Sorting takes O(n lg n) time, while finding the biggest element only requires an O(n) scan of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly done by defining a helper function that does the heavy processing work. Idiomatically this is named `go`.

```
place :: [Int] -> Int
place = go . quicksort
  where
  go numlist
    | length numlist /= 0 = biggestVal
    where biggestVal = head numList
```

Note that this function doesn't need guards:

```
place :: [Int] -> Int
place = go . quicksort
  where go (x:_) = x
        go _ = undefined  -- you didn't define this, what should you do??
```

Note also that to find the largest value in a list, you don't need to sort it first.

```
place [x] = x
place []  = undefined -- again: what should this be?
place xs  = foldr1 max xs
```

In fact, there's even a name for this:

```
place = maximum
```

It's even more polymorphic than you need:

```
maximum :: (Ord a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given by Adam, please think of the following:

1. Am assuming you were looking for the guard so that your call to `head` after `quicksort` does not fail. Try to look at it this way: would you even want to try to sort an empty list? Max of empty list would be an empty list, so if you put a guard upfront and only sort->head in case it is not an empty list.
2. In Haskell to check for empty list it is better to use `null` since `list` can be of infinite length.
3. If you want to implement your own max function then sorting just for taking max is overkill as the number of comparison would be more than required.